Initializing array elements inside a forEach
I declare an array, then set its arr.length property. When I try to initialize its elements inside a forEach loop via arr[index], it doesn't work and only those elements can be accessed/modified which have already been initilized outside forEach. Can someone please explain what's happening here?
const arr = [];
arr.length = 10;
arr[7] = 17;

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  arr[index] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
});

console.log(arr);

Output:
[ <7 empty items>, 4, <2 empty items> ]

So only arr[7] element is modified to 4 as a random value but other elements, since not initialized outside forEach, are still empty.

use array constructor to initalize

As for how to fix it, you can do const arr = Array(10).fill(undefined). Or if the arr[7] = 17 was just for demonstration, const arr = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)) directly.

Just started wondering how the forEach() itself iterates over the array. Because array is an object itself, is that so that the forEach only iterates over already set indices of the array object (in this case index 7)?

JS array has this unfourtunate "flaw", referred as "empty slots". Unfourtunately empty slots are skipped over when you are trying to map over them. see more details at https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/objects-classes/ch2.md#empty-slots
